# What is the minimum license needed for Power Automate service account to connect to SharePoint, Send emails, run scheduled/ instant/automate flows

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, flow, licensing

Our IT admin created a service account for me to create some flows of those types:

1. Scheduled
2. Instant
3. Automated

The flow mainly:

1. Connects to SharePoint lists
2. Sends emails using outlook

Now when I first access the power automate environment I was able to create a new solution and added the above flows without issues.. but today I wanted to share the flow with other users >> I got this popup that I need a license:

[image]

So what is the minimum or best license I need to not get the above message? as I do not want to create a trial license, I need a permanent license instead? any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your organization has access to Microsoft 365 Enterprise licenses, you can perform all the operations mentioned in your question using it.

Minimum Microsoft 365 enterprise license required for using Power automate flows, connecting to SharePoint online sites and sending emails using Outlook connector is **E1** plan.

You can check the compare the Microsoft 365 Enterprise licenses at: [Microsoft 365 Enterprise Software | Office 365 E1, E3, E5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-365/enterprise/compare-office-365-plans)

**Additional**: [Microsoft 365 and Office 365 plan options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-365-platform-service-description/office-365-plan-options)